# React Native Video plays sideways (rotated 90 degrees) on android

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

I'm trying to play a video on react-native-video recored with react-native-camera with:

```
<Video source={{ uri: video.uri }} 
    controls={true}
    paused={this.state.paused}
    style={videoStyle}
/>
```

On iOS video plays correctly, but on android the video plays sideways (rotated 90 degrees). I also tried with react-native-af-video-player and same result, iOS plays correctly but not android

Test video:

http://static.mstn.com/47a11184-b075-4f4c-8b2c-22ba6eb5caf5.mp4

Comment: can you show your styles as well?

Comment: Hi @NoobieSatan style is:
width and height are dynamically calculated, but if I put fixed values to them video still displays sideways
Style is:
const videoStyle = { borderRadius: 10, width, height };